# How do you run a test recorded from Selenium IDE on Selenium Grid2?

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide, selenium-grid

All of the examples in the unfortunately-sparse documentation are of tests coded by-hand in Ruby/Java/etc.  There's no mention of running tests recorded from the IDE (which are saved into HTML files).  And there's no allusion to any API methods for opening/parsing/evaluating/running said files.

Comment: this is multi step process, where are u stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no support in Grid to run tests using HTML files from IDE . You will have to use a programming language. You can find explanation/reason for this in the old selenium-grid page

http://selenium-grid.seleniumhq.org/faq.html#my_test_cases_are_in_html_selenese_how_can_i_run_those_against_selenium_grid_

No one stops you from creating one though :)